# Why the database verification code can not be executed in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

This is an existing class in the dll to verify that the database exists

```
public class CheckDataBaseExists
{
    public void CheckDataBase(string Server, string Database_name)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=" + Server + ";Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();

        con.InfoMessage += connection_InfoMessage;
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(@"if DB_ID('" + Database_name + "') is null print '" + Database_name + " is not exist !\r\nCreate new database ?'", con);

        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
        DataTable set = new DataTable();
        adp.Fill(set);

        con.Close();
    }

    public static void connection_InfoMessage( object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
    {
       if( MessageBox.Show(e.Message, e.Source, MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.Yes)
       {
           try
           {
```

The form of entering the name of the server and the database if the database did not exist

```
              #region create form 

           Label creating = new Label();
           creating = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
           creating.SuspendLayout();
           // 
           // creating
           // 
           creating.AutoSize = true;
           creating.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
           creating.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 12F);
           creating.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(25, 3);
           creating.Name = "creating";
           creating.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 19);
           creating.TabIndex = 0;
           creating.Text = "Creating database...";


           Form  create_db = new Form();
           create_db.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
           create_db.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
           create_db.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
           create_db.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 25);
           create_db.ControlBox = false;
           create_db.TopMost = true;
           create_db.Controls.Add(creating);
           create_db.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
           create_db.MaximizeBox = false;
           create_db.MinimizeBox = false;
           create_db.Name = "Create";
           create_db.ShowIcon = false;
           create_db.ShowInTaskbar = false;
           create_db.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
           create_db.Text = "Creating Databse...";
           create_db.ResumeLayout(false);
           create_db.PerformLayout();




           create_db.Controls.Add(creating);

           create_db.ShowDialog();
               #endregion
```

Read the file that contains the database name and the server

```
           string[] read_file = File.ReadAllLines(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\" + "ConReq.HP");
               string db_src = read_file[2],
                      db_nm = read_file[0].Substring(7, read_file[0].Length - 7),
                      db_server = read_file[1].Substring(7, read_file[1].Length - 7),
                      location = read_file[3];
```

The SQL file contains commands to create the database with the name of the database to be created

```
             string read_DBsql = File.ReadAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\Required\DB\DB.sql");
             read_DBsql = read_DBsql.Replace("DataBaseName", db_nm);
```

Create a connection and execute the command

```
               SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + db_server + ";Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True");
               con.Open();
             SqlCommand  comm = con.CreateCommand();
               comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
               comm.CommandText = read_DBsql;

               comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
               con.Close();



           }
           catch (Exception db_e)
           {
               MessageBox.Show(db_e.Message, db_e.Source, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
           }
           }


       }                 
    }
```

But what happens is that when a message appears make sure there is no database and  question is do you want to create one.
 when I want to create a new one, appears the Form created then nothing happens and remains visible. As in the pictures

[image: MessageBox asked if you want to create one]

[image: Form created]

Comment: That is a lot of code. Can you narrow down your problem to be more specific? Which line is it that you think goes wrong and what would you expect to happen instead?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what the problem is. That the MessageBox appears and does not go away? That the database is not created on the server at all? What SQL program (Oracle, SQL Server, etc) are you using? We might need to see the sql script too.

Comment: This is quite confusing, why are you using an adapter/table for a query that returns no rows?  & why are you using `PRINT` to return output (& presumably catching it in _InfoMessage) as opposed to just running a SELECT query?

Comment: @JacobH SQL Server , sql script has a lot of code, Created by Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: @AlexK. The code works well when placed inside the project directly
However, when the called dll contains cod. Nothing is executed...

Comment: Unrelated tips: `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataAdapter` are all `IDisposable` so each should be in a `using` block. Once you've done that, you don't need to worry about the `Close`, because that gets called by the implicit `Dispose` as you exit the `using` block. Beware constructing SQL queries with string concatenation because they are vulnerable to SQL injection attacks; use SQL parameters instead.

Answer (score 1):

Why you are using Info_Message  event for such simplest thing ( checking database)

Just check the result is below query:

String query = "select count(*) from sys.databases where name = 'dbname'"

Execute above query as:

var count = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

Also can you please show full code written in Info_Message

Comment: if( MessageBox.Show(e.Message, e.Source, 
              MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == 
               DialogResult.Yes)

Comment: string read_DBsql =  File.ReadAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory +  @"\Required\DB\DB.sql");
 read_DBsql = read_DBsql.Replace("DataBaseName","ExcelTest");

Comment: SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Data Source);
                   con.Open();
                 SqlCommand  comm = con.CreateCommand();
                   comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                   comm.CommandText = read_DBsql;
                   comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                   con.Close();

Comment: How you are closing create_db form.

Comment: Your messagebox and create_db both being shown as Dialog, this could be an issue